# How to see a class definition in python while using Jupyter Console?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Console for python programming. Sometimes I do a lot of things in the same session. It happens that I define a class in the earlier part of the session and later want to see the class definition. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: if you have current version of Jupyter try with class name and shift+tab probably will show definition of class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class docstring is accesible via:

```
%pdoc <class name>
```

good for user defined as well as builtin functions and classes,

Yet displaying a whole class is not available in ipython or Jupyter-console.
You can use:

```
<function name>??
```

for displaying a function within the class. 
see the following discussion: [how to print source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909536/how-to-print-source-code-of-object-i-defined-use-edit-magic)

For better interactive workflow try `Jupyter-notebook`

Comment: This does not help me. I already know how to print function docstring.

Comment: The class source code isn't available to display in Jupyter-console